# How to do infinite scroll with pagination in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. I want to do the pagination with a REST API. My question is how to add an infinite scroll and then load the data to the next page. How can I load to "https://MY_API_URL?page=**2**", page 3 and so on?

Comment: call your `getJSONData(int page)` as a result of calling `itemBuilder` and cache it somewhere (for example using `MapCache`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit** 
change sendPagesDataRequest to the following should work 
if json string you gave me is correct

```
Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {
      /*String url = Uri.encodeFull(
          'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');*/
      String url = Uri.encodeFull("https://MY_API_URL?page=$page");
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');

      /*String responseString = '''
      {"current_page": 1, 
"data": [ 
    { "id": 1, "title": "Germa", "likes": 5, "image": "https://picsum.photos/250?image=8"}, 
    { "id": 2, "title": "Jepun", "likes": 3, "image": "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"} 
    ], 
 "first_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=1", 
 "from": 1, 
 "last_page": 30, 
 "last_page_url": "https:/API_URLpage=30", 
 "next_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=2"
}
      ''';*/

      PagesData pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(response.body);
      return pagesData;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        /*return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');*/
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        /*return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');*/
      }
    }
  }
```

**Edit** 
**full code with new sendPagesDataRequest**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter_paginator/flutter_paginator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_paginator/enums.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

PagesData pagesDataFromJson(String str) => PagesData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String pagesDataToJson(PagesData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class PagesData {
  int currentPage;
  List<Datum> data;
  String firstPageUrl;
  int from;
  int lastPage;
  String lastPageUrl;
  String nextPageUrl;

  PagesData({
    this.currentPage,
    this.data,
    this.firstPageUrl,
    this.from,
    this.lastPage,
    this.lastPageUrl,
    this.nextPageUrl,
  });

  factory PagesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PagesData(
    currentPage: json["current_page"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    firstPageUrl: json["first_page_url"],
    from: json["from"],
    lastPage: json["last_page"],
    lastPageUrl: json["last_page_url"],
    nextPageUrl: json["next_page_url"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "current_page": currentPage,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "first_page_url": firstPageUrl,
    "from": from,
    "last_page": lastPage,
    "last_page_url": lastPageUrl,
    "next_page_url": nextPageUrl,
  };
}

class Datum {
  int id;
  String title;
  int likes;
  String image;

  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.likes,
    this.image,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    likes: json["likes"],
    image: json["image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "likes": likes,
    "image": image,
  };
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Paginator',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey<PaginatorState> paginatorGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Paginator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState
                  .changeState(listType: ListType.LIST_VIEW);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on),
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState.changeState(
                listType: ListType.GRID_VIEW,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
              );
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState
                  .changeState(listType: ListType.PAGE_VIEW);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Paginator.listView(
        key: paginatorGlobalKey,
        pageLoadFuture: sendPagesDataRequest,
        pageItemsGetter: listItemsGetterPages,
        listItemBuilder: listItemBuilder,
        loadingWidgetBuilder: loadingWidgetMaker,
        errorWidgetBuilder: errorWidgetMaker,
        emptyListWidgetBuilder: emptyListWidgetMaker,
        totalItemsGetter: totalPagesGetter,
        pageErrorChecker: pageErrorChecker,
        scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          paginatorGlobalKey.currentState.changeState(
              pageLoadFuture: sendCountriesDataRequest, resetState: true);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<CountriesData> sendCountriesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {
      String url = Uri.encodeFull(
          'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');
      return CountriesData.fromResponse(response);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {
      /*String url = Uri.encodeFull(
          'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');*/
      String url = Uri.encodeFull("https://MY_API_URL?page=$page");
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');

      /*String responseString = '''
      {"current_page": 1, 
"data": [ 
    { "id": 1, "title": "Germa", "likes": 5, "image": "https://picsum.photos/250?image=8"}, 
    { "id": 2, "title": "Jepun", "likes": 3, "image": "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"} 
    ], 
 "first_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=1", 
 "from": 1, 
 "last_page": 30, 
 "last_page_url": "https:/API_URLpage=30", 
 "next_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=2"
}
      ''';*/

      PagesData pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(response.body);
      return pagesData;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        /*return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');*/
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        /*return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');*/
      }
    }
  }

  List<dynamic> listItemsGetter(CountriesData countriesData) {
    List<String> list = [];
    countriesData.countries.forEach((value) {
      list.add(value['name']);
    });
    return list;
  }

  List<dynamic> listItemsGetterPages(PagesData pagesData) {
    List<Datum> list = [];
    pagesData.data.forEach((value) {
      list.add(value);
    });
    return list;
  }

  Widget listItemBuilder(dynamic item, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue[50]
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: item.image,
            placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
          ListTile(title: Text(item.title), subtitle: Text('Likes: ' + item.likes.toString()),),
        ],),
    );
  }

  Widget loadingWidgetMaker() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 160.0,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget errorWidgetMaker(PagesData countriesData, retryListener) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text("error"),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: retryListener,
          child: Text('Retry'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget emptyListWidgetMaker(PagesData countriesData) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('No countries in the list'),
    );
  }

  int totalPagesGetter(PagesData pagesData) {
    return pagesData.lastPage;
  }

  bool pageErrorChecker(PagesData pagesData) {
    //return countriesData.statusCode != 200;
    return false;
  }
}

class CountriesData {
  List<dynamic> countries;
  int statusCode;
  String errorMessage;
  int total;
  int nItems;

  CountriesData.fromResponse(http.Response response) {
    this.statusCode = response.statusCode;
    List jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    countries = jsonData[1];
    total = jsonData[0]['total'];
    nItems = countries.length;
  }

  CountriesData.withError(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }
}
```

**Edit** 
you need to change `sendPagesDataRequest`, I use static string 
Assume your json string like this

```
{"current_page": 1, 
"data": [ 
    { "id": 1, "title": "Germa", "likes": 5, "image": "image url"}, 
    { "id": 2, "title": "Jepun", "likes": 3, "image": "image url"} 
    ], 
 "first_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=1", 
 "from": 1, 
 "last_page": 30, 
 "last_page_url": "https:/API_URLpage=30", 
 "next_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=2"
}
```

**Edit working demo**

[image]

**Edit full code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter_paginator/flutter_paginator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_paginator/enums.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

PagesData pagesDataFromJson(String str) => PagesData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String pagesDataToJson(PagesData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class PagesData {
  int currentPage;
  List<Datum> data;
  String firstPageUrl;
  int from;
  int lastPage;
  String lastPageUrl;
  String nextPageUrl;

  PagesData({
    this.currentPage,
    this.data,
    this.firstPageUrl,
    this.from,
    this.lastPage,
    this.lastPageUrl,
    this.nextPageUrl,
  });

  factory PagesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PagesData(
    currentPage: json["current_page"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    firstPageUrl: json["first_page_url"],
    from: json["from"],
    lastPage: json["last_page"],
    lastPageUrl: json["last_page_url"],
    nextPageUrl: json["next_page_url"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "current_page": currentPage,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "first_page_url": firstPageUrl,
    "from": from,
    "last_page": lastPage,
    "last_page_url": lastPageUrl,
    "next_page_url": nextPageUrl,
  };
}

class Datum {
  int id;
  String title;
  int likes;
  String image;

  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.likes,
    this.image,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    likes: json["likes"],
    image: json["image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "likes": likes,
    "image": image,
  };
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Paginator',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey<PaginatorState> paginatorGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Paginator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState
                  .changeState(listType: ListType.LIST_VIEW);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on),
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState.changeState(
                listType: ListType.GRID_VIEW,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
              );
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState
                  .changeState(listType: ListType.PAGE_VIEW);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Paginator.listView(
        key: paginatorGlobalKey,
        pageLoadFuture: sendPagesDataRequest,
        pageItemsGetter: listItemsGetterPages,
        listItemBuilder: listItemBuilder,
        loadingWidgetBuilder: loadingWidgetMaker,
        errorWidgetBuilder: errorWidgetMaker,
        emptyListWidgetBuilder: emptyListWidgetMaker,
        totalItemsGetter: totalPagesGetter,
        pageErrorChecker: pageErrorChecker,
        scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          paginatorGlobalKey.currentState.changeState(
              pageLoadFuture: sendCountriesDataRequest, resetState: true);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<CountriesData> sendCountriesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {
      String url = Uri.encodeFull(
          'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');
      return CountriesData.fromResponse(response);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {
      String url = Uri.encodeFull(
          'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');
      String responseString = '''
      {"current_page": 1, 
"data": [ 
    { "id": 1, "title": "Germa", "likes": 5, "image": "https://picsum.photos/250?image=8"}, 
    { "id": 2, "title": "Jepun", "likes": 3, "image": "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"} 
    ], 
 "first_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=1", 
 "from": 1, 
 "last_page": 30, 
 "last_page_url": "https:/API_URLpage=30", 
 "next_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=2"
}
      ''';

      PagesData pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(responseString);
      return pagesData;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        /*return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');*/
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        /*return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');*/
      }
    }
  }

  List<dynamic> listItemsGetter(CountriesData countriesData) {
    List<String> list = [];
    countriesData.countries.forEach((value) {
      list.add(value['name']);
    });
    return list;
  }

  List<dynamic> listItemsGetterPages(PagesData pagesData) {
    List<Datum> list = [];
    pagesData.data.forEach((value) {
      list.add(value);
    });
    return list;
  }

  Widget listItemBuilder(dynamic item, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue[50]
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: item.image,
            placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
          ListTile(title: Text(item.title), subtitle: Text('Likes: ' + item.likes.toString()),),
        ],),
    );
  }

  Widget loadingWidgetMaker() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 160.0,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget errorWidgetMaker(PagesData countriesData, retryListener) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text("error"),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: retryListener,
          child: Text('Retry'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget emptyListWidgetMaker(PagesData countriesData) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('No countries in the list'),
    );
  }

  int totalPagesGetter(PagesData pagesData) {
    return pagesData.lastPage;
  }

  bool pageErrorChecker(PagesData pagesData) {
    //return countriesData.statusCode != 200;
    return false;
  }
}

class CountriesData {
  List<dynamic> countries;
  int statusCode;
  String errorMessage;
  int total;
  int nItems;

  CountriesData.fromResponse(http.Response response) {
    this.statusCode = response.statusCode;
    List jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    countries = jsonData[1];
    total = jsonData[0]['total'];
    nItems = countries.length;
  }

  CountriesData.withError(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }
}
```

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paginator 
It will auto call your `REST` with `page` parameter 
In the following demo, I add print message , so you can see it auto call rest with page when scroll down
You can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
Future<CountriesData> sendCountriesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {
      String url = Uri.encodeFull(
          'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');
      return CountriesData.fromResponse(response);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');
      }
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full demo code

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:io';

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    import 'package:flutter_paginator/flutter_paginator.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_paginator/enums.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Paginator',
          home: HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return HomeState();
      }
    }

    class HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
      GlobalKey<PaginatorState> paginatorGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Paginator'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
                onPressed: () {
                  paginatorGlobalKey.currentState
                      .changeState(listType: ListType.LIST_VIEW);
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on),
                onPressed: () {
                  paginatorGlobalKey.currentState.changeState(
                    listType: ListType.GRID_VIEW,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                  );
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
                onPressed: () {
                  paginatorGlobalKey.currentState
                      .changeState(listType: ListType.PAGE_VIEW);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Paginator.listView(
            key: paginatorGlobalKey,
            pageLoadFuture: sendCountriesDataRequest,
            pageItemsGetter: listItemsGetter,
            listItemBuilder: listItemBuilder,
            loadingWidgetBuilder: loadingWidgetMaker,
            errorWidgetBuilder: errorWidgetMaker,
            emptyListWidgetBuilder: emptyListWidgetMaker,
            totalItemsGetter: totalPagesGetter,
            pageErrorChecker: pageErrorChecker,
            scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              paginatorGlobalKey.currentState.changeState(
                  pageLoadFuture: sendCountriesDataRequest, resetState: true);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
        );
      }

      Future<CountriesData> sendCountriesDataRequest(int page) async {
        print('page ${page}');
        try {
          String url = Uri.encodeFull(
              'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?page=$page&format=json');
          http.Response response = await http.get(url);
          print('body ${response.body}');
          return CountriesData.fromResponse(response);
        } catch (e) {
          if (e is IOException) {
            return CountriesData.withError(
                'Please check your internet connection.');
          } else {
            print(e.toString());
            return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');
          }
        }
      }

      List<dynamic> listItemsGetter(CountriesData countriesData) {
        List<String> list = [];
        countriesData.countries.forEach((value) {
          list.add(value['name']);
        });
        return list;
      }

      Widget listItemBuilder(value, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Text(index.toString()),
          title: Text(value),
        );
      }

      Widget loadingWidgetMaker() {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 160.0,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }

      Widget errorWidgetMaker(CountriesData countriesData, retryListener) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(countriesData.errorMessage),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: retryListener,
              child: Text('Retry'),
            )
          ],
        );
      }

      Widget emptyListWidgetMaker(CountriesData countriesData) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('No countries in the list'),
        );
      }

      int totalPagesGetter(CountriesData countriesData) {
        return countriesData.total;
      }

      bool pageErrorChecker(CountriesData countriesData) {
        return countriesData.statusCode != 200;
      }
    }

    class CountriesData {
      List<dynamic> countries;
      int statusCode;
      String errorMessage;
      int total;
      int nItems;

      CountriesData.fromResponse(http.Response response) {
        this.statusCode = response.statusCode;
        List jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        countries = jsonData[1];
        total = jsonData[0]['total'];
        nItems = countries.length;
      }

      CountriesData.withError(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      }
    }
```

Output

```
I/flutter (20369): page 1
I/flutter (20369): body [{"page":1,"pages":7,"per_page":"50","total":304},[{"id":"ABW","iso2Code":"AW","name":"Aruba","region":{"id":"LCN","iso2code":"ZJ","value":"Latin America & Caribbean "},"adminregion":{"id":"","iso2code":"","value":""},"incomeLevel":{"id":"HIC","iso2code":"XD","value":"High income"},"lendingType":{"id":"LNX","iso2code":"XX","value":"Not classified"},"capitalCity":"Oranjestad","longitude":"-70.0167","latitude":"12.5167"},{"id":"AFG","iso2Code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan","region":{"id":"SAS","iso2code":"8S","value":"South Asia"},"adminregion":{"id":"SAS","iso2code":"8S","value":"South Asia"},"incomeLevel":{"id":"LIC","iso2code":"XM","value":"Low income"},"lendingType":{"id":"IDX","iso2code":"XI","value":"IDA"},"capitalCity":"Kabul","longitude":"69.1761","latitude":"34.5228"},{"id":"AFR","iso2Code":"A9","name":"Africa","region":{"id":"NA","iso2code":"NA","value":"Aggregates"},"adminregion":{"id":"","iso2code":"","value":""},"incomeLevel":{"id":"NA","iso2code":"NA","value":"Aggregates"},"lendingType":{"id":""
I/flutter (20369): page 2
I/flutter (20369): body [{"page":2,"pages":7,"per_page":"50","total":304},[{"id":"CIV","iso2Code":"CI","name":"Cote d'Ivoire","region":{"id":"SSF","iso2code":"ZG","value":"Sub-Saharan Africa "},"adminregion":{"id":"SSA","iso2code":"ZF","value":"Sub-Saharan Africa (excluding high income)"},"incomeLevel":{"id":"LMC","iso2code":"XN","value":"Lower middle income"},"lendingType":{"id":"IDX","iso2code":"XI","value":"IDA"},"capitalCity":"Yamoussoukro","longitude":"-4.0305","latitude":"5.332"},{"id":"CLA","iso2Code":"C6","name":"Latin America and the Caribbean (IFC classification)","region":{"id":"NA","iso2code":"NA","value":"Aggregates"},"adminregion":{"id":"","iso2code":"","value":""},"incomeLevel":{"id":"NA","iso2code":"NA","value":"Aggregates"},"lendingType":{"id":"","iso2code":"","value":"Aggregates"},"capitalCity":"","longitude":"","latitude":""},{"id":"CME","iso2Code":"C7","name":"Middle East and North Africa (IFC classification)","region":{"id":"NA","iso2code":"NA","value":"Aggregates"},"adminregion":{"id":"","iso2code":"","va
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, the body part here Paginator.listView() cannot change or remove?

Comment: You can not remove. it belong to this plugin, it integrate all related actions to this plugin

Comment: alright, I am confuse about how to add this plugin code with my code

Comment: you can put _buildImageColumn(data[index]) in listItemBuilder

Comment: plugin just integrate all actions to it. like empty data use emptyListWidgetMaker and error use errorWidgetMaker . you can copy paste full code and change to yours.

Comment: like this Widget listItemBuilder(value, int index) {
        return _buildImageColumn(data[index]);
      }

Comment: you can use this example full code as a template and change to yours slightly

Comment: you do not need to change loadingWidgetMaker , emptyListWidgetMaker, emptyListWidgetMaker just use template code.

Comment: please provide response.body to me. I can create a sample based on your request.

Comment: the page will load based on current_page

Comment: the response.body is like this    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        { 
           id: 1,
          title: German,
          likes: 5,
          image: image url,
    }, { 
           id: 2,
          title: Jepun,
          likes: 3,
          image: image url,
    },
],
"first_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 30,
    "last_page_url": "https:/API_URLpage=30",
    "next_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=2",

Comment: full demo is ready. just change sendPagesDataRequest to fit your request. you can see my update answer.

Comment: sir, thank you for your help, I have question wanna ask, Sir say I just need to change the sendPagesDataRequest to fit my request but I cannot get the response automatic? Do I need to put all the static string? Very sorry about that I first-time use flutter

Comment: responseString is used to simulate your api response, because I do not have your api, do you encounter any error?

Comment: so if I want to get the response.body I need to change to list? Because the API response is show like what I am given

Comment: I have update my answer. you can just change  MY_API_URL and try again.

Comment: @chunhunghan Hi sir, I am follow your code. I have problem when I press id 1 image it will show the image 2 id. Do you know why?

Comment: @qing, this demo is about scrolling. could you post your code to another new question. so more people can help you, thanks.

Comment: You can read this article: https://medium.com/@e200/flutter-infinite-scroll-with-rest-api-2b11f64b9d02

Comment: hello @chunhunghan how to get **iso2Code** key value you just shown how to get **name**  and i also tried both api format but getting issue like res.body is not completely loading in flutter - json_response_flutter [link](http://prntscr.com/t4shhm) but my php_json is correct [link](http://prntscr.com/t4sgxc)

Comment: @ChauhanAjay, could you post your reproduce code and related full json to a new question to allow more people can help you. thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan brother my question limit is over :( could you plz help me out i just tried with online api still same issue it stuck at page=2 or page=3 or sometime at 10 or 11

is it possible to bind two or more values of countries.data so that i can use that method. Thank you

Comment: assume you mean list.add("${value['name']} ${value["iso2Code"]}"); to show country and iso2code together. I can't reproduce stuck in my example.

Comment: @chunhunghan hey bro this this is my last doubt bocz m not able to get what i want can you plz tell me how to resolve this error check this [link](http://prntscr.com/t4znb2) ----- also list.add("${value['name']} ${value["iso2Code"]}"); i added the key but not able to bind with text eg: Text(value['iso2Code'])

Comment: @chunhunghan I implemented this and it works fine, but why it stops after 5 pages in my app even if there are more than 100+ pages

Answer (score 7):

Infinite Scrolling Pagination is a tough task.

Besides just fetching new items lazily, you want to keep the user posted on your current state.
For example, if you're loading the first page, you might want to show a progress indicator in the middle of the screen. But, if you're loading a subsequent page, you probably want to show a progress indicator at the bottom. The same is true for error indicators.

You also need to stop requesting new pages if the list from the server is either empty or completed.
Not even to mention that you probably want to add "retry" buttons for failed requests.

There's now a package called [Infinite Scroll Pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) that can handle everything for you, and the usage is pretty simple.
To showcase that, I'll use the same country list example from @chunhunghan answer:

```
class CountryListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountryListViewState createState() => _CountryListViewState();
}

class _CountryListViewState extends State<CountryListView> {
  static const _pageSize = 20;

  final PagingController<int, Country> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void _fetchPage(int pageKey) {
    RemoteApi.getCountryList(pageKey, _pageSize).then((newItems) {
      final isLastPage = newItems.length < _pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => PagedListView<int, Country>(
        pagingController: _pagingController,
        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Country>(
          itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => CountryListItem(
            country: item,
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

In the code above, all of the issues I listed in the beginning (and others) are addressed, and you can customize everything if you need.

*Disclosure: I'm the package author, so feel free to message me with any doubts you may have.*

Comment: Nice. Thank you for your reply. I will try to use this package

Comment: @Edson you did a great job with this library!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a lightweight example of an infinite loading list with pagination. New items are requested as you reach the bottom of the list. Usage looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InfiniteList(
      widgetBuilder: (item) {
        return Text(item);
      },
      loadMore: (lastLoaded) {
        if (lastLoaded == null) {
          //first load request
          return ["hello", "world"];
        } else {
          //subsequent load request(s)
          return [];
        }
      },
      onItemSelected: (item) {
        print(item);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The idea is to paginate based on the last loaded item, `lastLoaded` rather than a page number. Doing this helps to ensure you don't miss or duplicate anything if the contents of page X+1 changes after you already loaded page X (i.e. when something is added or removed from the database).

If your API doesn't support that, or you don't want it, you could add a page number attribute to each of your items and then do:

```dart
something.load(page: lastLoaded.pageNumber + 1);
```

The implementation for InfiniteList looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension on List {
  Object lastOrNull() {
    return this.isNotEmpty ? this.last : null;
  }
}

typedef ItemWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(Object item);
typedef FutureItemsCallback = Future<List<Object>> Function(Object lastLoadedItem);

typedef ItemCallback = void Function(Object item);

class InfiniteList extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemWidgetBuilder widgetBuilder;
  final FutureItemsCallback loadMore;
  final ItemCallback onItemSelected;

  InfiniteList({Key key, @required this.widgetBuilder, @required this.loadMore, this.onItemSelected}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return InfiniteListState();
  }
}

class InfiniteListState extends State<InfiniteList> {
  List<Object> items = [];
  bool shouldTryToLoadMore = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    waitOnItems();
  }

  void waitOnItems() async {
    try {
      final items = await widget.loadMore(this.items.lastOrNull());
      this.shouldTryToLoadMore = items.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {
        this.items.addAll(items);
      });
    } catch(error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (items.isEmpty) {
      return initiallyLoading();
    } else {
      //TODO: show progress bar at the bottom if loading more
      return list();
    }
  }

  Widget list() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: shouldTryToLoadMore ? null : items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (shouldTryToLoadMore && index == items.length - 1) {
            waitOnItems();
            return null;
          } else if (index >= items.length) {
            return null;
          } else if (widget.onItemSelected != null) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () => {
                widget.onItemSelected(items[index])
              },
              child: widget.widgetBuilder(items[index]),
            );
          } else {
            return widget.widgetBuilder(items[index]);
          }
        }
      );
  }

  Widget initiallyLoading() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

A full gist is here:
https://gist.github.com/tombailey/988f788493cec9b95e7e9e007b8a7a0d

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

**screen_movie_listing.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenMovieListing extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenMovieListing({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenMovieListing> createState() => _ScreenMovieListingState();
}

class _ScreenMovieListingState extends State<ScreenMovieListing> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isLastPage = false;
  int currentPage = 0;
  int totalPage = 0;
  int totalItems = 0;
  var moviesList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _restAPICall(true);
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        if (!isLastPage) {
          _restAPICall(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _restAPICall(bool clearList) async {
    if (clearList) {
      currentPage = 1;
      moviesList.clear();
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    await RestAPIHelper.movieList(
      context: context,
      currentPage: currentPage.toString(),
    ).then((response) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });

      if (response.status!) {
        setState(() {
          currentPage = response.pagignation!.currentPage!;
          totalPage = response.pagignation!.totalPages!;
          totalItems = response.pagignation!.totalItems!;

          if (currentPage == totalPage) {
            isLastPage = true;
          } else {
            currentPage = currentPage + 1;
          }

          moviesList.addAll(response.moviesListFromAPIResponse!);

          if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter <= 0 && isLoading == false) {
            // This code will call the pagination API if more data is available and screen had covered content
            if (!isLastPage) {
              _restAPICall(false);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget _loadMoreIndicator() {
    return !isLastPage
        ? const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        : const SizedBox(height: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      controller: _scrollController,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: moviesList.length + 1,
      separatorBuilder: (_ctx, _index) {
        return SizedBox(height: 20);
      },
      itemBuilder: (_ctx, _index) {
        if (_index == moviesList.length) {
          return _loadMoreIndicator();
        } else {
          return ListItemMovie(data: moviesList[_index]);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**rest_api_helper.dart**

```
class RestAPIHelper {
  static Future<MoviesListModel> movieList(
    {BuildContext? context, String? currentPage = ''}) async {
    MoviesListModel? data;

    var bodyData = {
      'user_id': '1',
      'current_page': currentPage,
      'item_per_page': '1',
    };

    Map<String, String>? headerData = {
      'token': '1234567890',
    };

    try {
      final response = await http.post('api_url', headers: headerData, body: bodyData);
      var decodedResult = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data = MoviesListModel.fromJson(decodedResult);
      return data;
    } on SocketException {
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }

    return data!;
  }
}
```

**API Response**

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Movies Listing",
  "pagignation": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 7,
    "total_items": 7
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Movie Name",
      "image": "",
      "genre": "",
      "language": "Hindi",
      "release_year": "2022"
    }
  ]
}
```

> This example is based on API which have request parameter such as
> current_page, item_per_page & have response parameter such as
> current_page, total_pages, total_items

Answer (score 0):

```
I use ScrollController in Pagination ::

ScrollController? scrollController;

inside initState initialize it and pass the scrollListener function::

scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);

here is _scrollListener ::
- when extentAfter becomes 0 which means reached the bottom of last item you 
 call API again but you should also check if last page reached so that you 
 do not call API again when you reach last page , it is hashed inside the 
 condition

void _scrollListener() {
    debugPrint("extentAfter ::::: " +
        scrollController!.position.extentAfter.toString());
    if (scrollController!.position.extentAfter <= 0 /*&&
        viewModel.pageNumber < viewModel.totalCount + 1*/) {
      if (!viewModel.lazyLoading) {
        viewModel.lazyLoading = true;  //show a loading indicator
        // call APi again and inside getNewProducts "${pageNumber++}"
        viewModel.getNewProducts(viewModel.catId ?? ""); 
      }
    }
  }

then you pass scrollController to the listView/GridView controller ::

controller: scrollController,
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to implement the pagination myself, I would either use [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) library or, if the project is small and I just want it in one place and don't want to add yet another dependency, I would just wrap my `ListView` with `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` like below:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
  if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
    onScrollListener();
  }

  return true;
}

void onScrollListener() {
  if (reachedEnd) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isPageLoading) {
    isPageLoading = true;
    Future.microtask(() async {
      final newItems = await getItemsUseCase.get(page: nextPage);
      if (newItems.length < pageSize) {
        reachedEnd= true;
      } else {
        nextPage++;
      }

      allItems.addAll(newItems);
      isPageLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I've added a complete [code example here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/infinite-scrolling-sliverlist-in-flutter-2236aa050a6c).