# How to do pagination of the list with getting data from the API?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting data from an API server. Since a large amount of information is stored on the server, I do not need to receive all the information at once, but only upon request. With the help of the `limit parameter`, I set the number of elements that I will receive. I need to paginate a list. That is, display only 10 items, if you scroll down to load 10 more items, and so on. Can you please tell me how to implement this in my code?

**repository**

```
Future<List<PublicChargingStationModel>> get(
      {int? limit}) async {
    try {
      final apiKeyMap = await ApiKey.getCryptoApiKeyMap();

      final Uri url = Uri.parse(
        '${ApiConfig.schema}://${ApiConfig.domain}/${ApiConfig.uriPrefix}/stations/?limit=$limit',
      ).replace(queryParameters: apiKeyMap);

      final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as List;
        return data
            .map((json) => PublicChargingStationModel.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
      }

      return List<PublicChargingStationModel>.empty();
    } catch (_) {
      print(_);
      return List<PublicChargingStationModel>.empty();
    }
  }
```

**list**

```
child: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 44, top: 20, bottom: 14),
                child: Divider(
                  height: 0.5,
                  color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.20),
                ),
              )),
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: widget.stationList!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(widget.stationList![index].address,
                      style: constants.Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
```

Comment: This is actually infinite scrolling. This is given that the the app should fetch new data with the next limit on the API when the user scrolls to the end. Check out this package https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination it should do it, or this article if you want to build from scratch https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-infinite-scroll-pagination-flutter/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do infinite scroll with pagination in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234169/how-to-do-infinite-scroll-with-pagination-in-flutter) Just search and you shall find: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflutter%5D+infinite+scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two different ways like in first way you can create your own function where you can maintain pagination based on your screen pixels and you need to maintain one bool variable based on that decide that new page will be load or not. Just you need to give controller in listview builder.

Second option is using package which is [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) where you don't need to maintain any varibale or screen pixels just add your page request listener in pagination controller but you need to create pageview or different view where you can pass your list view and in pagecontroller property you just need to pass paginationcontroller that's it. Other all the things will be managed by your pagination controller.